# How is the sample size defined in a QAP test?

Tags: r

I often use `QAP` (quadratic assignment procedure) tests for significance testing of network statistics, but I've never really understood what the sample size actually is. The number of networks? Nodes? Ties?

I'm now trying to calculate confidence intervals for a `gcor` (in R package statnet) between two networks,  and seem to have hit a wall. From what I've read, there is no general consensus on what the (effective) sample size is. 
Can anyone give me any advice on what this should be?

I have two networks, each of 23 nodes. There are different numbers of ties in each each network.
If anyone has any ideas on this, I'd be very grateful! Hope this question isn't too vague, but I think the general issue may apply to a lot of network tests.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of graph correlation, the sample size is the number of {i,j} cells in the adjacency matrix, less the diagonal. In other words, it is the total number or potential ties in the network. In still other words, n * (n - 1) or [n * (n - 1)]/2 (if undirected), where n is the number of nodes. `gcor` evaluates the correlation between the presence or absence of a tie for each pair.

```
> g1 <- rgraph(10)
> g2 <- rgraph(10)
> gcor(g1,g2)
[1] -0.0784586
> vg1 <- gvectorize(g1, censor.as.na = F) #This creates a vector of all non-diagonal pairs in the network, with 0 or 1
> vg2 <- gvectorize(g2, censor.as.na = F)
> cor(vg1,vg2) #Good old fashioned Pearson correlation
[1] -0.0784586
```

In the specific case here, 23 * (23 -1) = 506 or [23 * (23 -1)] / 2 = 253.

Constructing a confidence interval for the correlation, however, is another matter entirely if you are using QAP. QAP is a non-parametric test, so the critical value you use in normal confidence interval construction (typically, ±1.96) is not appropriate.

Also note that there are other cases, especially for graph-level statistics, where the sample size is essentially 1, since the statistics are a property of the entire network. (Or 2 if you are comparing networks!)